# Extracting values using Regex - C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm not much familiar with Regular expressions. I've a string from which I need to extract specific values using regex. Here is the string

```
CN=ReportingGroup {b4f3d644-9361-461e-b604-709fa31f2b9e},OU=DOM USERS,DC=domain,DC=com
```

I want to get the values of CN and OU namely "ReportingGroup {b4f3d644-9361-461e-b604-709fa31f2b9e}" and "DOM USERS "

from the above string. How can i construct the regex pattern for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a RegEx for this.

If you split the string using `,` and then each resulting string with `=`, you can look through the keys in order to extract the value for the `CN` and the `OU` keys.

```
string cn;
string ou;
foreach(string adPortion in myString.Split(new Char [] {','}))
{
   string[] kvp = adPortion.Split(new Char [] {'='})

   if(kvp[0] == "CN")
      cn = kvp[1];

   if(kvp[0] == "OU")
      ou = kvp[1];
}
```

This assumes that `CN` and `OU` only appear once in the string.

Comment: I would advise against going this route. By performing manual splits, you would be effectively doing what Regex will do for you behind the scenes.

Comment: @Mr. TA - can you please expand on why a RegEx would be preferable?

Comment: Oded - Regexes were made specifically for the purpose of parsing strings. Your solution involves 12 lines of code, whereas with Regex, the whole thing fits into a one-liner. But line count aside, there's no reason at all to re-invent the wheel. Additionally, it's a good exercise for a beginner developer to learn Regex now that they have this relatively simple task to solve.

Comment: I would disagree with TA. Regex sometimes are an overkill for the application. IF you understand behind the scenes of regex (initializing a parser,scanner for tokens, building the parse tree etc....). But simple code like Oded will make it fast and makes much more sense.

Comment: I agree with @Oded here. Whilst the OP wanted a RegEx the provided solution is a perfectly acceptable alternative and easier to understand and therefore cheaper to maintain. When considering whether to use RegEx always remember the ancient proverb; "I used regular exressions to solve a problem. Now I have two problems."

Answer (score 5):

Do the following:

```
new Regex("CN=(?<CN>[^,]*),OU=(?<OU>[^,]*)").Match(str).Groups["CN"].Value;
```

Comment: @ NLV See what I mean?, If you are not a Regex expert it is plain Chinese to non-chinese people :)

Comment: this is good too but won't agree it's faster than oded's solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your string is pretty well structured. Consider using regular string functions like `IndexOf()` and `Substring()`. Regex are harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use Regex, the following code will iterate though all KEY=VALUE pairs:

```
        foreach (Match m in
            Regex.Matches(inputString, @"[,]*([^=]+)=([^,]*)"))
        {
            string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
            string value = m.Groups[2].Value;
        }
```